# Remotely Uninstalling CloudHealth Agents on AWS Windows Instances

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

We have about 3000+ AWS Windows EC2 instances that are running older versions of the CloudHealth agents (mostly 10.0.0.18 but there are others as well). All net new instances are getting v 10.0.0.22 and I have State Manager in AWS set to push v 10.0.0.22 to any instances that have no CloudHealth agent installed. My problem is that I can’t get the remote uninstall to work.
Through State Manager I’m running “msiexec /x CloudHealthAgent.msi /quiet” via PowerShell but this fails. If I log directly into the instances and I manually run “msiexec /x CloudHealthAgent.msi” I get the error:

“The installation package could not be opened. Verify that the package exists…”.

The ClodHealthAgent.msi does exist and lives in:

C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Downloaded Installations{875BF87C-67C8-4E38-ACAE-61EEC129430B}

If I run the following:

msiexec /x “{875BF87C-67C8-4E38-ACAE-61EEC129430B}”

I get the following error:

“This action is only valid for products that are currently installed”

It is installed and shows in Control Panel | programs and Features.

If I look at the registry under the path below there is no reference to this product.

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

I’m stumped, does anyone have any ideas on how I might get this uninstalled?

Comment: I'm getting closer to an answer. For my Windows 2019 instances I found that the path for "CloudHealthAgent.msi" is the following.

Comment: I'm getting closer to an answer. For my Windows 2019 instances I found that the path for "CloudHealthAgent.msi" is the following - C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Downloaded Installations\{875BF87C-67C8-4E38-ACAE-61EEC129430B} 
If I change to that folder and run the msiexec /x cloudhealthagent.msi it will uninstall. This path seems to be a concatenation of the LOCALAPPDATA path appended with Downloaded Installations\{875BF87C-67C8-4E38-ACAE-61EEC129430B} .

Comment: But on Windows 2022 instances it is a different path, C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Config\systemprofile\appdata\local\ownloaded Installations\{875BF87C-67C8-4E38-ACAE-61EEC129430B} and that does line up with any system variable path so I am not sure how I can move forward here.